# Windows Authentication (AD Authentication) to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, azure-active-directory, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ASP.net MVC Web application with on-premises Active Directory authentication, which I want to move to AWS PaaS service. My SQL database for the ASP.Net MVC web application will remain on-premises.

I did some research and found that AWS ECS is a good feature for containerization. But I am not looking for IaaS approach.

I am mainly looking for PaaS approach to migrate my on-premises application.

1. For the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Website, I am not finding an option to enable on-premises Active Directory Authentication. Is it possible?
2. Also can I connect to on-premises SQL server from AWS Elastic Beanstalk website using Windows Authentication/AD Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. I am using it.
It took lots of research and trial and error. As our AWS cloud VPC is in different domain than our on-prem AD domain and our users are in on-prem AD domain.

This is my setup.

We have setup managed AD in AWS domain (i.e. XYZAWS ) for my organization named XYZ which has one-way trust with our on-prem AD i.e. XYZ domain.

Now here is the catch when we deploy .Net application with windows authentication enabled to EB (elastic beanstalk) our EB server is running in AWS domain i.e. XYZAWS and that EB server is not domain joined by default so you need to domain join your EB server first and this domain join will happen with you on AWS managed AD i.e. XYZAWS domain.

As EB is domain joined to AWS managed AD that won't authenticate your on-prem AD users for that you need to impersonate your IIS app pool with a user which is in your on-prem AD.

For example I am impersonating my IIS identity pool with user XYZ\service-account-user and as I said we have one way trust between AWS managed AD and on-prem AD so your application should now be able to authenticate on-prem AD users bcoz you app is running as on-prem AD service account.

You have to include domain name while logging into your application
suppose user John has to login to app then he must login with user name "XYZ\john" and his password to let app authenticate him.

I have this whole setup automated using .ebextensions config files.
If I ever write blog on this will update it here.